# Access to home/work address stored in Google Maps ("My Place")

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to programmatically obtain the home/work address stored in Google Maps.
It is present (at least) in the Android version of Google Maps, under "My Places" in the web version, and it is used by Google Now.
I have looked at the API docs and the Android SDK, but have found no trace of it.
Anyone know if it is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: probably not relevant for you anymore, but check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39318135/5130239

Answer (score 1):

Home and Work locations from Google Maps are not available in any of the Google Maps APIs, it's not possible to access these locations via the APIs.

I would file a Feature Request on the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) to express your interest and share some use cases with the API team so they can consider this moving forward.