# Get Google users home and work locations

Tags: android, google-maps

In Google Maps, Google knows the address of where I work and live.

As an Android developer is it possible to access this information using the Google account that the device is currently connected to?

If this is possible would it be a Google Map API or one relating to accounts in Android?

Thank you

Edit :: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177235/how-to-get-the-user-home-work-location-for-a-user-in-android) question but there is no accepted answer.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource  check this link. You can get user details from this api but not work and home locations.