# Is there a way to get the user's "home" and "work" location through a Google API?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm working in Android with the Google Maps API, and having the user set a "Home" location in my app. What I would like is when they click the search box, to automagically suggest the "work" and/or "home" location that they've saved in their Google Maps application.

I realize this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177235/how-to-get-the-user-home-work-location-for-a-user-in-android) but it was never really answered, and it was a year and a half ago, so I'm hoping perhaps this data is more accessible.

To be clear, I'm looking for some location services API call built in, or even a Google+ endpoint where I could GET this information. Or even if that is simply not possible at this time, that'd be nice to know.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: looks like this question is addressed in this SO question as well:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429292/get-users-home-work-and-starred-locations-like-google-inbox-does/32602023#32602023

Comment: check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39318135/5130239

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the user Home/Work location for a user in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177235/how-to-get-the-user-home-work-location-for-a-user-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

**No**, that's not possible via an API call.

Workarounds if you need an address are already mentioned here: [How to get the user Home/Work location for a user in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177235/570168)